# Use java classpath in scala from wildfly

Tags: java, scala, wildfly

I am using `Scala` version 2.11.8 and run it from war-application deployed on `wildfly`. Structure of war file is following:

*----META-INF*

*----WEB-INF*

*------lib*

I want to use libs in scala classpath that are located in `WEB-INF/lib`. Java application sees these libs by default. 
But scala doesn't see them, even when I use it with flag "use java classpath" - 
 `settings.usejavacp.value=true` 
(we set up `scala` settings programmatically).

This war file is unpacked in some temp package inside `$JBOSS_HOME`. (I can't deploy application manually into *standalone/deployments*)

Do somebody know how to get full path to this temp directory for including it directly in scala classpath? 
Or how to make flag "*use java classpath*" working in `scala` from `wildfly`?